# Как пустить 2д луч в сторону курсора

Tags: c#, unity3d

делаю 2д игру, хочу сделать атаку по врагу при помощи рейкаста.как пустить именно 2д луч в сторону курсора.В 3д пространстве это легко,но вот в 2д...

Comment: А чем 3D проще?

Comment: там для этого есть метод вроде Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointRoRay(Input.MousePosition); а вот в 2д это не прокатит(((

Answer (score 0):

```
ray.origin = откуда
ray.direction = (куда - откуда).normalized
```

Comment: в том то и дело что когда я так делаю у меня почему то луч только на правую часть от персонажа и он не по мышке,а выше градусов на 40

Comment: возможно, с координатами что-то не так. Точка - начало луча и курсор находятся в одной и той же системе координат?

Comment: вот это я незнаю типо я начало беру transform.position а конец тоесть направление Input.MousePosition это в 1 системе находится?

Comment: Мышь может в экранных координатах работать, я не знаю, как в это вашем unity. Выведите обе координаты, когда мышь рядом с началом.